# -Bash command not found appearing every time I start terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

every time I start my terminal, it always says "-bash:  .: command not found" twice.  Does anyone know how I can get rid of that?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have an errant command in a file like .bashrc or .profile. Try opening those files and looking for a command that doesn't belong. If something look suspect you might want to copy and paste it into Terminal to see if it runs correctly.

You might also check your prompt if you've customized it to see if you introduced an error there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look into your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile files with a text editor. You probably mistipped something you have a `.` or some other character that is being executed at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, review the .profile ( /Users/yourusername/.profile ), it sure has something like that *.:*

Just remove it from there and it will stop showing up.